# How to update particular field in mongo db by using MongoRepository Interface?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mongodb, mongorepository

How to update a particular field in mongo db collection by using MongoRepository Interface in spring?

Comment: apart from MongoRepository do you know with any other repository?

Comment: short answer is NO

Comment: did you get the solution?

Answer (score 9):

You can update specific field by below code:

```
Query query1 = new Query(Criteria.where("id").is("123"));
Update update1 = new Update();
update1.set("available", false);
mongoTemplate.updateFirst(query1, update1, Customer.class);
```

Comment: This method uses MongoOperation, not MongoRepository

Comment: Not an answer, see the previous comment

Answer (score 4):

As of today, you can't update the document using `MongoRepository` using one query. If you really want to update a particular field using `MongoRepository` then following is the steps:

1. Fetch the document that you want to update
2. Set the new value to a particular field and save that document.

Example:

```
MyDocument myDocumentToUpdate = myDocumentRepository.findById(documentId); // fetching a document that you want to update the field
myDocumentToUpdate.setMyField(myNewValue); // setting the new value to the field myField
myDocumentRepository.save(myDocumentToUpdate); // saving (It basically updates the document) the updated document
```

Comment: This seems to have the effect of overwriting the entire document rather than just updating the value of that single field.

Comment: Yes. Internally it is not changing the particular field but as a user, it seems to do so.